# Passing ViewModel - View to Controller When JavaScript disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

It's difficult for me for developping an functionality without JavaScript..

I have a ViewModel :

```
public class AccountRegisterViewModel
{
    #region Properties
    public User User { get; set; }
    public ExternalAccounts ExtAccounts { get; set; }
    public LocalPassword Password { get; set; }
    public Company CompanyARegister { get; set; }
    public Company CompanyBRegister { get; set; }
    public bool SameCompanies { get; set; }
    public int NbCompanies { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

In view, i have a link with checkbox for copying the first company with the second
But I don't know how pass this viewModel (View to Controller) for keeping my data and return the same View with the copie of company..

i try this, in view :

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Click", "CopyCompanies","Account", new { model = Model })             
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.SameCompanies)
```

In Controller  :

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CopyCompanies(AccountRegisterViewModel model)
    {

        ...
        if (model.SameCompanies)
        {
           // copie
        }else //clear
        ...
        return View("Step2Register", model);
     }
```

Any idea ?? Thank you for your help

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Without JavaScript checkboxes are only good in forms. The only things that can do something without JavaScript are direct links or forms and the only way to pass 'modified' data are forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the CopyCompanies action method requires the AccountRegisterViewModel object, then you will need to provide it. Unfortunately, you will not be able to provide the value using the approach you are following when creating the link.

Your two options would be to have a hidden field for each property in AccountRegisterViewModel and then let the model binding create the object, but even this would not be ideal, since the viewModel is composed of complex objects, so you would have way too many hidden fields.

Your second option, which I think is a better approach, would be to pass in some kind of Id that corresponds to the AccountRegisterViewModel that CopyCompany can use to look up the values it would need.